# Trouble accessing SqlCommand type properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I currently am working on a second form within my project. My SQL Command is an update command that will edit an existing row, so my form opens on a `CellMouseDoubleClick` Event so that I can edit the row, submit my changes and then update the database. 
Ideally, I would like to have these two lines at the start of my code.

```
public partial class EditData : Form

    {
        SqlConnection strCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CQ_DATA;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateQuery", strCon);
```

But obviously I cannot as this causes an error with the compiler.

I wish to do this because I have two functions.

Firstly:

```
public EditData(string name, string surname, string CompName, string Address, string MoNo, string PoNo, string AreaCode, string Email, string Date)
```

Takes in the initial values of the row from the double click event and loads it onto some text boxes, and also saving these as the original parameters in the sqlCommand, such as

```
txtName.Text = name;
searchCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
```

And then secondly I have a submit button

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Which re-validates all my textboxes using validation code I've written and tested before. After checking they're valid I add these as the paramaters I want to change the old ones to

```
searchCommand.Parameters.Add("@NewName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
```

And then I simply execute the Nonquery.

```
strCon.Open(); //OPEN CONNECTION
                //searchCommand.CommandText = "SP_UpdateQuery";
                searchCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                strCon.Close();
```

I attempted to use Global variables and ran into some issues whenever I ran the form twice. I never really wanted to stick with globals anyway, so could anyone suggest some improvements to my logic or code? 
The key two lines

```
SqlConnection strCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CQ_DATA;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateQuery", strCon);
```

Where should I put them/how should I better use them?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix.
Simply don't initialize the value to begin with.

```
SqlConnection strCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CQ_DATA;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand searchCommand;
```

Instead put it in the constructor which occurs first and once anyway.

```
public EditData(string name, string surname, string CompName, string Address, string MoNo, string PoNo, string AreaCode, string Email, string Date)
        {

            searchCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateQuery", strCon);
```